# In CUDA compute capability 3.5+, can all threads (on an SM) really have 255 registers each?

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I'm looking at the following maximum values for different CUDA compute capabilities:

1. Registers per thread
2. Registers per SM (symmetric multiprocessor)
3. Threads per SM

as appearing [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA). Well, it looks like for CUDA 3.5 and upwards at least, 1 x 3 > 2 . That implies that while a single thread can use up to 255 registers, if too many threads attempt to do so there will be register spill. Is my interpretation correct? Or is stated figure 1. not really correct and it's really 64 registers per thread?

Comment: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities

Comment: Register assignment is performed statically at compile time without reference to execution parameters. So no, your interpretation is wrong.

Comment: @talonmies: So, is the table wrong? Or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: I would say you are reading it wrong.  The table in question is organized similarly to table 12 in the programming guide.  The incorrect method of reading it would similarly produce an incorrect conclusion if you applied it to individual limits of threads per block in the x, y, and z dimensions, and then attempted to infer total threads per block from that.  There is an additional limit on threads per block (in aggregate) which also must be adhered to, and is also specified. Likewise the total number of registers in a SM is an additional aggregate limit.

Comment: No, your model of register spilling is wrong, The compiler determines registers per thread and spilling statically, If you request too many threads, the kernel launch fails. This is all covered with great clarity in the programming guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than wikipedia, we can use documentation provided by NVIDIA to answer these questions.

The [table 12 of the programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__technical-specifications-per-compute-capability) indicates that (for cc3.5):

1. The *maximum* registers per thread is 255
2. The maximum number of threads per block is 1024
3. The maximum registers per multiprocessor is 64K (i.e. 65536)

Registers per thread is decided at compile-time, is a specific number, and does not vary at runtime.  Likewise, "spilling" as used in this context is a decision made at compile-time.

Therefore, I cannot simultaneously use 255 registers per thread while launching a threadblock of 1024 threads (1024 * 255 = 255K > 64K)

But if I launch a threadblock of 64 threads, I can certainly use up to 255 registers per thread, legally, with a properly launching threadblock.

Therefore, like some other CUDA constraints (such as the individual dimensions of a threadblock and the aggregate number of threads in a threadblock), the individual constraint of registers per thread is one limit, but the maximum number of registers per multiprocessor is another (aggregate) limit, and *both* must be satisfied, *at launch*, for a kernel to launch.  If there are other threadblocks currently resident, this could impact occupancy.  If there are no threadblocks currently resident, and the limits cannot be met, this is a condition that is detectable at launch-time and will be reported as a kernel launch error (too many resources requested for launch).

Comment: Actually the same explanation could be made using the table on Wikipedia... the main point is indeed that the collective constraint needs to be satisfied at launch, so **if you have a block with many threads, all of them are constrained to a lower number of registers**.